# Write an INNER JOIN in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL query. I would like to know how to write the same query in LINQ and C#.

```
select ph.Id,p.Id as projInfoId, ph.Title, ph.AdditionalHours, ph.AdditionalCost,
    ph.InsertDate, ph.InsertBy, ph.LastUpdateDate, ph.LastUpdateBy, ph.TeamId, 
    ph.ProjInfoId
from tblTeamType t 
    join ProjInformation p on t.team_id = p.teamId
    join projProject pj on p.projectId=pj.projectId
    inner join ProjInfoAdditionalHrs ph on p.teamId = ph.teamId and p.Id = ph.proJinfoid
```

Comment: What have you done so far?  Have you tried Google?

Comment: yes I have tried this code

Comment: So post your code.

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), and show your own first efforts so we can see where *specifically* you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier to translate SQL using query comprehension syntax instead of lambda syntax.

General rules:

1. Translate inner queries into separate query variables
2. Translate SQL phrases in LINQ phrase order
3. Use table aliases as range variables, or if none, create range
   variables from table names abbreviations
4. Translate IN to Contains
5. Translate SQL functions such as DISTINCT or SUM into function calls
   on the entire query.
6. Create anonymous objects for multi-column grouping or joining

Using these rules, you should get something like:

```
var ans = from t in tblTeamType
          join p in ProjInformation on t.team_id equals p.teamId
          join pj in projProject on p.projectId equals pj.projectId
          join ph in ProjInfoAdditionalHrs on new { p.teamId, p.Id } equals new { ph.teamId, ph.proJinfold }
          select new {
              ph.Id,
              projInfoId = p.Id,
              ph.Title,
              ph.AdditionalHours,
              ph.AdditionalCost,
              ph.InsertDate,
              ph.InsertBy,
              ph.LastUpdateDate,
              ph.LastUpdateBy,
              ph.TeamId,
              ph.ProjInfoId
          };
```